# Grails.Domain class. belongsTo.Why?

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

now, i try understend how works in Grails domain class and GORM.
So, i try experiments:

i experiment with two domain class: Main and Sub.

Let's go!

STEP 1:

```
class Main {
    String name;
    String value;
}

class Sub {
    String name;
    String value;
}
```

Look MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE `sub` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

RESULT: Expected. All nice.

STEP 2:

```
class Main {

     String name;
     String value;
     Sub sub;
}

class Sub {

     String name;
     String value;
}
```

Look MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK3305B98FB5DA4E` (`sub_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK3305B98FB5DA4E` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_id`) REFERENCES `sub` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE `sub` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

RESULT: Expected. All nice. In terms of MySQL we have a unidirectional relationship 1:1. main -to- sub. Yes?

STEP 3:

```
class Main {

    String name;
    String value;
    Sub sub;
}

class Sub {

    String name;
    String value;

    static belongsTo = Main
}
```

Look MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK3305B98FB5DA4E` (`sub_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK3305B98FB5DA4E` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_id`) REFERENCES `sub` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE `sub` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

RESULT: In terms of MySQL we have a unidirectional relationship 1:1. main -to- sub. Yes? 
 but this is the same that on STEP 2. but we have differents domain class on STEP 2 and on STEP 3.
 ie, method belongsTo does not affect the structure of the table?

STEP 4:

```
class Main {

    String name;
    String value;
    Sub sub;
}

class Sub {

    String name;
    String value;

    static belongsTo = [main:Main]
}
```

Look MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK3305B98FB5DA4E` (`sub_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK3305B98FB5DA4E` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_id`) REFERENCES `sub` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE `sub` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

RESULT: In terms of MySQL we have a unidirectional relationship 1:1. main -to- sub. Yes? 
 but this is the same that on STEP 2 and 3. but we have differents domain class on STEP 2 and on STEP 3 and on STEP 4.
 Look 3 most recent example, we can conclude that the method belongsTo does not affect the structure of the table... but, but, but.. look on this STEP

STEP 5:

```
class Main {

    String name;
    String value;
}

class Sub {

    String name;
    String value;

    static belongsTo = [main:Main]
}
```

Look MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE `sub` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `main_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK1BE407E56D06` (`main_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1BE407E56D06` FOREIGN KEY (`main_id`) REFERENCES `main` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

In this example, belongsTo affects the structure of the table, so which makes belongsTo???

Comment: OK. So what is the question you would like to ask specifically? Perhaps this could help: http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.1%20Association%20in%20GORM

Comment: My specific question: what role does belongsTo for a table? I've done many examples - and the only one I saw a change in the table

Comment: BTW if you want two-way 1:1 association, managed by Grails, put `belongsTo` to BOTH classes. And Grails doesn't completely support 1:1 for now, IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per grails documentation belongsTo indicates how operations cascade. This does not necessarily set the cascades in the database but affects the behaviour of `save()` and `delete()` operations in GORM.

So this answers why there is absolutely no difference in SQL between STEP2 and STEP3.

In STEP5 you reverse the direction of your relationship so `Main` no longer know about the `Sub`.

Comment: For a in-depth coverage of this topic, look up Peter Ledbrook's ecxellent series GORM Gotchas (http://blog.springsource.com/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/)